# JSP 2 Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, el

I read tutorials at [courses.coreservlets.com](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) (it is on a PDF file so I cannot directly link the exact part of the topic). On JSP 2 Expression Language topic, the author shows comparison between JSP 1.2 and JSP2.

**On JSP 1.2:**

```
<BODY>
<jsp:useBean id="randomNum"
             type="coreservlets.NumberBean"
             scope="request" />
<H2>Random Number:
<jsp:getProperty name="randomNum"
                 property="number" />
</H2>
</BODY></HTML>
```

**On JSP 2:**

```
<BODY>
<H2>Random Number:
${randomNum.number} 
</H2>
</BODY></HTML>
```

`randomNum` is just a variable name of NumberBean class right? On JSP 1.2 it shows, but on JSP2 its just a one line.

My question is on JSP 2 how will server know that randomNum is NumberBean because I did not see any part of the code that will tell that `randomNum` is NumberBean?

I hope I made question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't know, actually it's searching the page context in any scope to find a variable with the name `randomNum` when evaluate an EL expression.

Comment: Hi Roman C, thanks for answering my question. I try to review the tutorial and I saw the page context (my bad because I did not pay attention on that part, I thought that it is explaining difference of old and new version of jsp). it has an example of <%= pageContext.findAttribute("name") %>
<jsp:useBean id="name" type="somePackage.SomeClass"%>. And looking on others questions here I noticed that it is placed before <html>, is that correct?

Comment: it doesn't matter, JSP is running on the server, not on the client.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand how will I do it? I am trying to search examples on google but I cannot find anything.

Comment: Note, scriptlets are discouraged in JSP 2.0, use JSTL or other expression languages. In the controller use `request.setAttribute("randomNum", getNumberBean());`. Make sure you create and populate the bean before.

Comment: I have not seen JSTL yet, but I will note that. Know I understand that using setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue") which data will be stored in HttpServletRequest, HttpSession, or ServletContext (application). Then when i use ${attributeName} server will find that attribute in order of request, session and application. If in any case those 3 have the same attribute name the value from request (or HttpServlet) will return. Is that right?

Comment: You have forgot the page scope, then depending on the expression language you use, JSTL EL will return the object as soon as it find it.

Comment: yes I missed PageContext. how will I know which scoped was returned? In "real web applications", Is it usual to use same attributeName on those four?

Comment: In "real web applications" you know in what scope you put the object, and use that scope to get it back. JSTL EL uses all scopes because it depend on the page context implementation and you didn't point it to the right scope.

Comment: OK, so the code that I saw was for example purposes only. Thank you very much Roman C for making it clear to me. :)